# How to fix a blackberry browser input from going black on focus?

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile

I recently upgraded our mobile application to use JQM 1.1.1, and noticed a very big problem on Blackberry 6 browsers.

The screenshots tell the story best.

In the first image you'll see the search text box rendered correctly.

However in the second image you'll see that when the input text box is focused, it makes the textbox black

Please see my screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Has anyone seen this issue?

Comment: I suggest setting-up a JSFiddle to demo the problem.

Comment: It looks like there's no need to use JSFiddle to demo it because the screenshots are using the Jquery mobile demo site.  Public and no custom code. Here's the link: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/#/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-search.html

Comment: Not relevant to your issue, but RIM is failing horribly so you won't have to worry about blackberry development much longer.|https://www.google.ca/finance?client=ob&q=TSE:RIM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and fixed it with css like this:

```
input.ui-focus, textarea.ui-focus {
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer.
From my side, I had to set css to:

```
.ui-btn.ui-focus, .ui-input-text.ui-focus, ui-input-search.ui-focus
```

Hope it will help!